# Android View Pager deleting images from folder not refreshing

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

Whenever i delete my Image from my ViewPager. Then sometimes next Image will be deleted.or sometime's no image delete.

where i am wrong i dont know.

My **GallaryActivity**

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton imgBtnDelete;
    TextView tvImageCount;
    ViewPager galleryViewPager;
    GalleryAdapter adapter;
    private static String filePath = "";
    public int mPosition = 0;

    // File Code
    public File mDirectory;
    File[] imageList;
    ArrayList<Integer> mTotalImages = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> mFilePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri[] mUrls;
    String[] mFiles, mFileNames;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the Status bar...Write Before setContentView()
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        imgBtnDelete = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnDelete);

        imgBtnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

        // File Code
        mDirectory = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "CameraApp/Images");

        imageList = mDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
                return ((name.endsWith(".jpg")) || (name.endsWith(".png")) || (name.endsWith(".mp4")));
            }
        });

        int imgLength = (imageList == null) ? 0 : imageList.length;
        if (imgLength > 0) {
            mFiles = new String[imgLength];

            // add imgLength here for set Total Images in TextView
            for (int k = 0; k < imageList.length; k++) {
                mTotalImages.add(imgLength);
                filePath = imageList[k].getAbsolutePath();
                mFilePaths.add(filePath);
            }

            mFileNames = new String[imgLength];

            tvImageCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvImageCount.setText(1 + "/" + mTotalImages.size());

            mUrls = new Uri[imgLength];

            int i, j = 0;
            for (i = imgLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                mFiles[j] = imageList[i].getAbsolutePath();
                mFileNames[j] = imageList[i].getName();
                j++;
            }

            galleryViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.galleryViewPager);
            adapter = new GalleryAdapter(this, mFiles);
            galleryViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            galleryViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
        } else {
            tvImageCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please capture some images from App!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
            tvImageCount.setText((position + 1) + "/" + mTotalImages.size());
            Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "mPosition is :  " + mPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    };

    private void openAlert() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Delete Image")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this Image?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                        DeleteImage();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .show();
    }
```

my **DeleteImage()**

```
private void DeleteImage() {
    File file = new File(mFilePaths.get(mPosition));
    boolean deleted = file.delete();

    if (deleted) {
        mFilePaths.remove(mPosition);
        if (mFilePaths.size() == 0) {
            tvImageCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if (mFilePaths.size() != 0 && mFilePaths.size() != 1) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            galleryViewPager.setCurrentItem(mPosition + 1);
        }
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } else {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgBtnDelete:
                if (mDirectory.exists() && mDirectory != null && mFilePaths.size() != 0) {
                    openAlert();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No Images to Delete!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

and following is my **GallaryAdapter** of Viewpager

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    private String[] mFiles;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context mContext, String[] mFiles) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mFiles = mFiles;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFiles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallary_viewpager_item, container, false);

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewCenterGallery);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        Bitmap bitmap;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFiles[position], options);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

Comment: After delete you need to delete the file from file list and bind the file again in adapter.

Comment: bro you asking me...?...or telling me for do that

Comment: openAlert() is available in adapter class? show me how can you call openAlert method?

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: Hello bro...what happen...if you are not free..then do your work...you will tell me when you will be free...Ok tnx

Comment: hey bro...you will tell me about delete() or not....plz leave comment here when you free...otherwise i will post it as a new question...let me know when you become free ok.Tnx

Comment: Hi, i need to see.. how can you call openAlert method? are you calling from item listener?

Comment: bro..see i added openAlert() in Question...i updated que.....look at onClick()  in Question....in which see on 3rd Case on Switch().........case R.id.imgBtnDelete:

Comment: ohh sorry i see, but why are you using filename from getFileName()... why you are not using specific file from File[] files? its easy for you if you are using file from files array and remove file from list and storage and update list as well in adapter.

Comment: i think you have more experience in java or some others lang....(:

Comment: bt if you tell me which is in less line....then plz post here....bcz now i am going home to my comp....after 5 to 10 mnts.

Comment: its better you can use position from files array and manage. i can't explain you in detail.

Comment: but both are same or not...?....i am delete using file Name or else using as you said..

Comment: yes for storage is same but how can you manage with your array, you need to also delete same file in array and update array in adapter

Comment: ok bro. i will do it tomorrow..i will try..and let you know..if any prob. will occur then i will leave comment here...ok tnx for your great help.

Comment: Hello bro. i have some mistake's on deleting..):...i did as you say....i am posting my delete code..in Question. in 5 mnts.

Comment: i updated my whole question.

Comment: hey Tnx my Gujrati bro. i solved my Delete Problem.....again tnx. Bro.

Comment: Great, up  vote and enjoy

Comment: bhai me already tara Question ne up vote & accept karelo j che....have kaya ne karu...??

Comment: Hey....Jaydip bro.....me che ne kale Pachu Check karyu...ke  Image Captured karu tyare e ViewPager  ma First dekhai.....pan tyar pachi Jyare Back Activity kari ne New Captured karu...Ne Fari  Pachu  ViewPager kholu to....Last Captured Image Second Aave che...dar  vakhate...??

Comment: Free. hoi ne Idea hoi to Keje Bhai...aaje kale game tyare.

Comment: Bhai Jd....plz khabar hoi to 1 mnt. time kadhi ne comment...kari de....ke jyare Second Time GalleryActivity kholu chu tyare...kem Last Captured image First aavti nai Hoi...???...Delete karya Pachi nathi aavti.

Comment: Delete ma pan...kai Nai....khali ene Adapter mathi Remove karavu chu...bus ane pachi Adapter ne Refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
if (imgLength > 0) {
        mFiles = new String[imgLength];

        mFileNames = new String[imgLength];

        mUrls = new Uri[imgLength];

        int j=0;
        for (int i = imgLength-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mFiles[j] = imageList[i].getAbsolutePath();
            mFileNames[j] = imageList[i].getName();
            j++;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image Name - " + Arrays.toString(mFileNames), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            galleryViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.galleryViewPager);
            adapter = new GallerySlideImageAdapter(this, mFiles, mFileNames);
            galleryViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please capture some images from App !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: no bro...no changes...i gave up for this issue...):

Comment: old adapter which you are using first time

Comment: now okay you can check and know me its working fine or not

Comment: bro...i checked with your method and my old adapter..but same issue

Comment: please debug and check files in which order its showing...its issue in order you need to just fix order

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFiles[position], options);..........this line of adapter alaways set first images of Folder in my view pager...but without this line i can not go for another

Comment: 3rd Toast...like this.........{1st ImageName,2nd ImageName,3rd ImageName}

Comment: Ohhhh Bro....you are great..great super...you solved my problem..Tnx tnx

Comment: but one Query plz dont angry me...you already gave meyour more time...all are ok...but when i Delete my view pager Image...it will be delete....but i am not getting an second images.

Comment: mns my image deleted from myapp or phone...but i am not showing an next images at that time...i already used notifyDatasetChanged() after delete. fun.

Comment: you need to again bind the list in adapter or notify the adapter.

Comment: please tell me about this in just new que..i will up vote that que. too.

Comment: where is delete code, can you show me how can you delete image?

Answer (score 0):

Sort your file list as per latest to older datetime and bind files in adapter.

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles(); //your files object

Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>(){
  public int compare(File f1, File f2)
  {
    return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
  } 
});
```

Comment: tnx for comment..bt how can i do this..i mean where..?

Comment: after get files list and you can get create datetime in file object and sort files using date time

Comment: i am trying..after it i will tell you what happens.

Comment: Hey bro...i did it..but no changes...):

Comment: i know my Problem is in adapter...in this Line.............Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFiles[position], options);

Comment: my adapter will be always sets my images with position[0]...that is why i can not fetched last captured images...

Comment: but i dont know how can i avoid this problem.

Comment: also in my Default gallary my images shown as you mentioned well....but not in My View Pager...):

Comment: that's why we have sort the file list

Comment: yes, its okay, can you please check files string array is sorted as per your last image or not?

Comment: then what can i do next...bcz i m trying to solve this since 2 days

Comment: no i didn't do that.....files string array is sorted as per your last image or not.
plz tell me how can i check this.

Comment: your last caputure image is showing in 0 position or last position of mFiles?

Comment: bro...i said in my question....i print an Toast...that toast gave me a last captured imageName

Comment: otherwise do one thing remove sort code and make reverse loop like
 for (int i = imgLength-1; i >= 0; i--) {

Comment: for using my own Function i got last captured image....i posted it here....but using that function viewpager display 1 image multiple times

Comment: private Drawable getImageFromSdCard(String imageName) {
        Drawable d = null;
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/CameraApp/Images/";

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/" + imageName);
            d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return d;
    }

Comment: but when i used above fun. in my adapter...how can i set getCount() of Adapter..?

Comment: yes bro...but not now...when i am using above function at that time...i got an drawable of Last Image....but at that time i m not using above Files...like mFiles[].

Comment: see updating question...see my adapter

Comment: now when i use this adapter..i fetch last captured image...but the next thing's is getCount()...now got it bro..what i told you

Comment: Okay, use one veriable for counter file and when counter increase and get file then after just notify the adapter

Comment: you are doing wrong way...do it you have done in first time.

Comment: whats wrong bro..which code...tell me bcz it is urgent...i will accept + vote up your answer.

Comment: in your adapter  GalleryActivity activity = new GalleryActivity();
    String ImageName = activity.getFileName();

Comment: its return always one name

Comment: but you are getting only one image String ImageName = activity.getFileName();
can you show me your getFileName() funcation

Comment: added 2 function's in question.

Comment: its return last file path in this funcation? how can you get all files in adapter, it showing alway one file

Comment: yes i did it first time...and this is my 1st app. this issue was become more complex for me..):

Comment: means i will go on my First adapter way...?

Comment: see my another answer and try this way